# REST API: Show each unique item only once while retrieving categories from a list

Tags: rest, splistitem, list-item

In my SP2013 environment I've a function which returns items from a list using REST. Let's say it only returns the items' category which is defined in the column "Category". It works just fine.

Some of the items are in CategoryA, some in CategoryB etc. so the output is something like this:

> CategoryA
>
> CategoryA
>
> CategoryA
>
> CategoryB
>
> CategoryB
>
> CategoryB
>
> CategoryC
>
> CategoryC

Now I'd like to trim out the results so that each category is mentioned **only once**.

What are my options? Is there a jQuery trick for this, can RESTful function do the job or could some of the SharePoint's options help me (I wonder if e.g. lookup columns could help me here somehow)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx), `Grouping` is not supported.

The solution, is to apply grouping for the JSON results returned from REST endpoint.

### How to group array results using jQuery

```
function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}


var catalog = { products: [
   { category: "Food & Dining"},
   { category: "Techonology"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"}
]};

var categoryNames = groupBy(catalog.products, 'category');
console.log(categoryNames);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/auB6B/)

### Example

Suppose the following function is used for getting list items via SharePoint REST API:

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then the following example demonstrates how to print unique task names:

```
getListItems('https://tenant.sharepoint.com/project','Tasks','?select=Title',
    function(items){    
       var taskNames = groupBy(items,'Title');
       console.log(taskNames);
    },
    function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

Comment: This seems right, but I haven't still managed to get the code to work successfully. The problems lies between my inexperience and different current code. The code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3kpyxg7z/. I use the dataTable library to list my items on a table. I wonder how to apply the grouping for the results in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have drop-down list that I populate using element fetched from a SharePoint list.Some of the rows are repeated, in order to eliminate the repeats this is what I use.

JQuery:

```
 var alreadyUsed = {};
 $("#dropdownCharts > option").each(function () {
 if (alreadyUsed[this.text]) {
     $(this).remove();
 } else {
     alreadyUsed[this.text] = this.value;
 }
 });
```

Probably you can adapt it to your specific circumstances.

I hope this helps.